# Setting WPF's Textblock.Text property throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textblock

```
textBlock.Text = "Text";
```

This is my code, and it shows no errors.
but when I run it, I get a `NullReferenceException`

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This statement is inside a ValueChanged event of a Slider, should it matter.

Comment: NullReferenceException happens at runtime, not compile time.  In your cs file, where are you setting the .Text property?  It is possible that the instance has not yet been created.

Comment: @billb It's inside the window with the XAML and everything.

Comment: i am sure that this information is definitely not enough to propose some solution.. if i am not wrong you are trying todo something like this..  TextBlock TextBlock = null;
            TextBlock.Text = "Text";

Comment: @bathineni I really said everything. :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume this code is in your constructor. Make sure `InitializeComponents` is called before you execute this line:

```
public YourWindow()
{
    TextBlock.Text = "Text"; // <- bad
    InitializeComponents();
    TextBlock.Text = "Text"; // <- good
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a little bit of context for this line of code. I have no idea, where you are executing it.

Comment: I Edited the question. ("I'm writing this inside a ValueChanged of a Slider.")

Comment: @Ken: There is no XAML that defines the TextBlock.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it? I don't quite understand. sorry. (I just started using WPF for something and just a beginner in C#, so sorry for being stupid)

Comment: @Ken: How did you declare that `TextBlock` variable? How did you put it into your form?

Comment: Dragged it from the Visual Studio's Toolbox.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you, if you don't give me the info I need. Please show me the XAML code of that TextBlock.

Comment: I did, it's in the question. I'll copy it to here too:
`<Slider Height="23" Name="TypeSlider" Margin="0,6,0,7" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" ValueChanged="ChangeType" Minimum="1" Maximum="4" Value="1" />`

And the code is inside ChangeType

Comment: @Ken: Seriously, are you kidding me??? This is the XAML code for the **Slider** not for the **TextBlock**.

Comment: Wow, I said I'm a newbie ><. here it is:
`<TextBlock Name="TypeBlock" Text="type" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Margin="17,8,17,11" />`

Comment: @Ken: Nope, that isn't it either. If it were, you would be using `TypeBlock.Text = "Text"` instead of `TextBlock.Text = "Text"`. Please highlight `TextBlock` in your code and hit F12 and paste here whatever it shows you. If F12 doesn't do anything, use right click -> "Go to declaration" instead...

Comment: I didn't actually use the name TextBlock, I only wrote it here so you'd understand. I pressed F12 and it gave me the latest XAML I gave you. (the TextBlock one)

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying. I'll just make a new project, I probably messed some up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If this is at compile time and not even at runtime it seems like your reference to the Textblock object isnt' right.

Is this exactly your code?
Try the following in your XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" />
```

And in your CS File:

```
myTextBlock.Text = "Text";
```

Answer (score 1):

The "valuechanged" event happens already inside the InitializeComponent() call.
So what you might need to do in your algorithm is check if the textbox == null (and don't do anything if this is true!..).

Had the same issue, but already had this thread open so..  It's late, but hopefully it'll help someone else soon :)

Answer (score 0):

If your TextBlock definition is other than this `<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock"/>` then your program does not compile at all.

But if it is like that then just make sure `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor of your window is executed before accessing any childs.